# Finding $\dfrac{d^nx}{dy^n}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y$ is a function of $x$, then what is the relation between $\dfrac{d^nx}{dy^n}$ and $\dfrac{d^ny}{dx^n}$? If we were to talk about $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$, then they both are reciprocals of each other.

We cannot simply take the reciprocal of $\dfrac{d^ny}{dx^n}$, can we?

Comment: Set $y=x^2$ and $n=2$. What do we get?

Comment: And then still with $y=x^2$, see what happens for $n=3,4,5,\ldots$

Comment: @O.L. $\dfrac{\pm 1}{8y^{3/2}}\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}$

Comment: @Théophile for $n=2,3,4...$ we can say that $\dfrac{d^ny}{dx^n}.\dfrac{d^nx}{dy^n}=0$ as $\dfrac{d^ny}{dx^n}=0$...

Comment: This may help: [Is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ not a ratio?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-fracdydx-not-a-ratio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in doubt, use the chain rule.  Repeatedly differentiate both sides with respect to $y$ as follows:
$$
y = f(x)\\
1 = f'(x) \cdot \frac{dx}{dy} \implies \frac{dx}{dy} = 1/f'(x) \\
0 = f''(x) \left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2 + f'(x) \frac{d^2x}{dy^2} \implies\\
\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} = -\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)} \left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2
\implies\\
\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} = 
-\frac{f''(x)}{[f'(x)]^3}
$$
That is, at a given point $(x,y)$, we have
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} = -\frac{d^2y/dx^2}{(dy/dx)^3}
$$

Comment: Will we be able to generalize it for any n?

Comment: @user157130 I'm not sure how exactly this would generalize

Comment: @user157130 that being said, it is possible to continue this process indefinitely by differentiating both sides with respect to $y$ yet again.

Comment: Yes..that is correct..and thanks for your help!