# 2nd derivative using rule of implicit differentiation (Economics)

Tags: calculus, economics, implicit-differentiation

This may well be a stupid question. I'm currently trying to find out whether a production function I have has convex isoquants.

I'm aware I can find the derivative $\frac{dL}{dK}$ by using the rule of implicit differentiation:

$$\frac{dL}{dK} = -\frac{∂Q}{∂K}/\frac{∂Q}{∂L} $$

Where Q is the production function.

Is it possible to find the second derivative in a similar way? i.e.

$$\frac{d^2L}{dK^2} = -\frac{∂^2Q}{∂K^2}/\frac{∂^2Q}{∂L^2} $$

Comment: take a look at something similar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072869/why-doesnt-it-work-when-i-calculate-the-second-order-derivative/1072948#1072948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The equation is **not** the result of *implicit differentiation*. It is the result of *total differentiation*:

$$dQ(K,L)=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial L}\cdot dL+\frac{\partial Q}{\partial K}\cdot dK=0$$

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial L}\cdot dL=-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial K}\cdot dK$$

Dividing the equation by $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial L}$ and $dK$ gives the final result.

Comment: then, how is this answers the OP question?

Comment: I just made a clarification.